# yum groupinfo not showing anything after yum clean all

Tags: python, yum

I am using createrepo command through my python code to update repo meta data.

Below is an exmaple for the same.

/var/www/html/repo1 is my base working dir for the repo1

```
cmd = "createrepo -g comps.xml /var/www/html/repo1"
ret, status = commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
```

after this from command line if I do `yum groupinfo <group_name>` it shows the group information for group_name but if I do `yum clean all` then it does not show the group information. It throws a warning saying group does not exist.

Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the `repodata` directory under `/var/www/html/repo1` contain the `comps.xml` file you expect it to? Do you have a repository configured in yum for `/var/www/html/repo1`? Does running `yum clean all; yum makecache; yum groupinfo <group>` work?

Comment: Yes i have comps.xml under /var/www/html/repo1 and my repo is also configured properly as i can search and install packages.

Comment: Running `yum clean all; yum makecache; yum groupinfo <group>` works for me. i am wondering if we can make it persist across yum clean operation

Comment: `yum clean all` is *supposed* to clean the metadata cache up. That's the point. That said yum *should* be automatically rebuilding it again. What's the config for your repo look like exactly? Do you have an `mdpolicy` line for it? If you run `yum clean all; yum repolist; yum groupinfo <group>` does it work? Or `yum clean all; yum info <package from your repo>; yum groupinfo <group>`?